# Completing a track in Trackmania

Tags: trackmania-series

To complete the track in Trackmania Nations Forever, the car must first go through all checkpoints *in any order*, then go through the finish block.

Is this true for all games of the [Trackmania series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrackMania) that have been published so far (see list below)? If not, which games do not have this rule?

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid we don't have a crystal ball...

Comment: @badp What do you mean?

Comment: What about future games in the series? ☺

Comment: @badp Thanks, good point, I haven't thought about that: question edited! Please let me know if that's okay now.

Comment: @badp I've added the list of the games I was implicitly referring to.  Please let me know if you still need a crystal ball to answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to these [posts](http://forum.maniaplanet.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=29765), completing a track in any Trackmania game requires either:

- 1 start + 0 or more CPs + 1 or more finishes
- or 1 multilap + 1 or more CPs + 0 or more finishes.